# Android working with URIs

Tags: android, file, upload, uri

I am writing an app that can upload files. The files are either received by using `StartActivityForResult` or received via share menu from other apps.

I have run into some problems with receiving files via share menu, specifically determining the file info. Before an upload i need to know the name and size of the file. When sharing from apps like gallery app or Google Photos, everything works fine - URI with `content://` scheme is received and i can use `ContentResolver` to get the name and size. But from some apps i receive a URI with `file://` scheme and the same method doesn't work anymore. Is there a way to get file info from URIs with both schemes? And is there a way that guarantees that it will work for all possible URIs?

Code for getting file info:

```
string folderName = "";
Android.Net.Uri tempUri = null;
switch (Intent.Action) {
case Intent.ActionSend:
    var result = Intent.GetParcelableExtra (Intent.ExtraStream);
    tempUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(result.ToString());
    break;
case Intent.ActionSendMultiple:
    var uris = Intent.GetParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.ExtraStream);
    tempUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(uris[0].ToString());
    break;
}

if (tempUri != null) {
    var cursor = this.ContentResolver.Query (tempUri, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.MoveToFirst ())
        folderName = cursor.GetString (cursor.GetColumnIndex (Android.Provider.OpenableColumns.DisplayName));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get file info from URIs with both schemes?

Wrap the `file:` or `content:` `Uri` in [a `DocumentFile`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html). Then, call `getType()` and `length()` on the `DocumentFile`. In the case of `file:` and `getType()`, I presume that `DocumentFile` is using `MimeTypeMap` under the covers to try to guess a MIME type.

> And is there a way that guarantees that it will work for all possible URIs?

No.